# sed/awk + count char until relevant char

Tags: sed

Dear friends

I have the following:

```
   PARAM=1,2,3=,4,5,6,=,7#,8,9
```

How to count by sed/awk the even "=" character between PARAM until "#" character

For example

```
 PARAM=1,2,3=,4,5,6,=,7#,8,9
```

Then sed/awk should return 3

OR

```
 PARAM=1,2,3=,4=,5=,6,=,7#,=8,9
```

Then sed/awk should return 5

THX

yael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this one liner. No need to use `split()` as in the answer. Just use gsub(). It will return the count of the thing that is replaced. Also, set the field delimiter to "#", so you only need to deal with the first field.

```
$ echo "PARAM=1,2,3=,4,5,6,=,7#,8,9" | awk -F"#" '{print gsub("=","",$1)}'
3
$ echo "PARAM=1,2,3=,4=,5=,6,=,7#,=8,9" | awk -F"#" '{print gsub("=","",$1)}'
5
```

Comment: That will fail if there's an equal sign before or within "PARAM" (the OP specified 'between PARAM until "#" character'. I'm not sure what is meant by "even" in 'the even "=" character'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk script that finds the count using field separators/split.  IT sets the field separator to the # symbol and then splits the first word (the stuff to the left of the first # on the `=` character.  An odd approach possibly, but it is one method.  Note that it assumes there are no `=` characters to the left of param.  If that is a bad assumption, this will not work.

```
BEGIN{ FS="#" }
/PARAM.*#/{
   n = split( $1, a, "=" );
   printf( "Count = %d\n", n-1 );
}
```

It can be done with one line as well:

```
[]$ export LINE=PARAM=1,2=3,4=5#=6
[]$ echo $LINE | awk 'BEGIN{FS="#"}/PARAM.*#/{n=split($1,a,"="); print n-1;}' 
3
```

Comment: it possible to write this in one line
Because I need to run the awk in bash script
yael

Comment: for example echo $LINE | awk ........
(in LINE I have the (PARAM=1,2,3=,4=,5=,6,=,7#,=8,9)
yael

Comment: @yael, I added a one-line example.

Comment: OK thanx
the second quastion if I not have the "#" char , then how to change the awk syntax to count the "=" char ,the target is to support the two cases (1) case if I hace "#" , and the second case if I dont have the "#" char

Comment: /PARAM.*#/  --> how to change it to support until end of line or until "#" char
yael

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what you are asking.  The /PARAM.*#/ just specifies what lines the code block applies to.

Comment: but if export LINE=PARAM=1,2=3,4=5=6 , then awk not print any count
my target to change the awk to print the count also if "#" not defined in the LINE
yael

Comment: I see what you are asking.  You could change it simply to /PARAM/.  Or even just remove it and use awk 'BEGIN{FS=#"}{n=split...}